# Bootstrap with Spring MVC

Tags: css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I am trying to use bootstrap to style my app but I won't apply the styles.  This is what is in my JSP

```
<c:url value="css/bootstrap.min.css" var="cssBoostrap" />  
<link href="${cssBootstrap}" rel="stylesheet">
```

This css folder is on the same level as WEB-INF not inside of it but it won't work if it is inside of it or even if the files are inside of the view dir.  What could the problem possibly be?  I no longer get the no mapping error when adding the mapping to my servlet.xml but yet it still doesn't see the file or I can assume it doesn't because no styling is applied, then I change it to link to the online hosted version and all my styles are applied correctly.

Servlet XML

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


<!-- Scans for annotated @Controllers in the classpath -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.eaglecrk.recognition" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:properties/system.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- messageSource -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>file:${external.property.directory}PMS.EOTM.SendEmail</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- dataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.eaglecrk.recognition.persistence" />
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="javaMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value = "${email.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${email.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${email.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${email.password}" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">${email.mail.smtp.ssl.trust}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">${email.mail.smtp.starttls.enable}</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${email.mail.smtp.auth}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Controller

```
package com.eaglecrk.recognition.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSourceAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.eaglecrk.recognition.dao.award.AwardDao;
import com.eaglecrk.recognition.dao.award.AwardDaoInterface;
import com.eaglecrk.recognition.dao.employee.EmployeeDaoInterface;
import com.eaglecrk.recognition.model.AwardTypeModel;
import com.eaglecrk.recognition.model.EmployeeModel;
import com.eaglecrk.recognition.persistence.AwardNomination;
import com.eaglecrk.recognition.persistence.AwardType;
import com.eaglecrk.recognition.persistence.Employee;
import com.eaglecrk.recognition.util.Functions;
import com.eaglecrk.recognition.util.SpringMailSender;

@Controller
public class TestController extends BaseController implements MessageSourceAware {

private static final Logger LOG = LogManager
        .getLogger(TestController.class);

@Autowired
private EmployeeDaoInterface employeeDao;

@Autowired
private AwardDaoInterface awardDao;

@Autowired
private SpringMailSender springMailSender;

/**
 * @param request
 * @return (ModelAndView) object
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView test() {
    try {
    LOG.info("Entered the controller");
    springMailSender.sendMail();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Employee> employees = employeeDao.findAll();
    Collections.sort(employees, Functions.lastNameOrder);
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        EmployeeModel model = new EmployeeModel(employee);
        names.add(model.getLocation().getLocationId() + " " + 
        model.getFirstName() + " " + model.getLastName());

    }
    mav.addObject("names", names);
    mav.setViewName("test");
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addNomination(
        @ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") AwardNomination nomination,
        ModelMap model) {

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("login");
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/newAwardType", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addAward() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    ArrayList<AwardTypeModel> models = new ArrayList<AwardTypeModel>();
    try{
    AwardTypeModel newAwardTypeModel = new AwardTypeModel();
    newAwardTypeModel.setActive(false);
    newAwardTypeModel.setName("AwardTypeModel.name");
    newAwardTypeModel.setDescription("AwardTypeModel.description");
//      newAwardTypeModel.setId(123456);
    newAwardTypeModel.setCreated(new Date());
    newAwardTypeModel.setModified(new Date());
    models.add(newAwardTypeModel);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mav.addObject("awardTypes", models);
    mav.addObject("model", new AwardTypeModel());
    mav.setViewName("addAward");
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/addAward", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addAwardForm(@ModelAttribute("model") AwardTypeModel model, BindingResult result){

        model.setCreated(new Date());
        model.setModified(new Date());

    AwardType dbo = (AwardType) model.convertToDb();
    awardDao.save(dbo);
    return "redirect:/test";

}

@Override
public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

Comment: Post your controller which is calling this jsp.

Comment: I can get it to work if I link to <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> like that but for some reason when I add the files locally in a folder called css under my WEB-INF directory and configure it in my servlet.xml it doesn't see the style

Comment: WEB-INF is not a public folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create one folder by name resources at same level as WEB-INF as shown below:

```
    WebApp-|    
           | - resources -|
           |              |-styles-|
           |              |        |-bootstrap.min.css
           |              |
           |              |-javascript-|
           |                           |-example.js
           |
           | - WEB-INF
```

**Include the following line in your servlet xml:**

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Access these resources in your jsp as:

```
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/styles/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/javascript/example.js" />"></script>
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare in your dispatcher servlet config the location of you resources (e.g js, css, img etc.) :

`<mvc:resources mapping="/public/**" location="/public/" />`

`location` contains the path to your resources folder. `mapping` is how you call your resources in your jsp.

Don't forget to declare your mvc namespace in dispatcher config.

Comment: I am using Spring IDE and it is yelling at me after I add these to my servlet, I get a red line in the </beans> tag at the very end of the file

Comment: I think it's because you didn't add the XML namespace related to mvc. add this : `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"`, and this : `"http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd` in your `xsi:schemaLocation`, present in `<beans>` element.

Comment: That is all there, added my whole servlet to my post if you want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Following Prasads Answer above if you need Java based configuration for the same use -

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.eaglecrk.recognition")
@EnableWebMvc  
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  

@Bean  
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {  
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();  
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");  
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");  
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);  
    return resolver;  
}  

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
}
```

Also if you are using xml based configuration don't forget `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>`